# Discrete time impulse response

Tags: linear-algebra, control-theory, linear-control

The following question is from a System Theory exam whitout answers or solutions:

Which of the following discrete-time state-space model (A,B,C) of the form

$x(t+1)=Ax(t)+Bu(t), \quad y(t)=Cx(t), \quad t \in N$

With $A$ in Jordan frm has its impulse response given by

$ 
    h(t)=\left\{
                \begin{array}{ll}
                  1, \quad t=4
                  \\
                  0, \quad t \neq 4
                \end{array}
              \right.
 $

$A)
\left[ \begin{array}{c|c}
A & B \\
\hline
C &  
\end{array} \right] = \left[ \begin{array}{cccc|c}
0&1&0&0&0 \\
0&0&1&0&0 \\
0&0&0&1&0 \\
0&0&0&0&1 \\
\hline
1&0&0&0  
\end{array} \right]
$

$B)
\left[ \begin{array}{c|c}
A & B \\
\hline
C &  
\end{array} \right] = \left[ \begin{array}{cccc|c}
0&1&0&0&1 \\
0&0&1&0&0 \\
0&0&0&1&0 \\
0&0&0&0&0 \\
\hline
0&0&0&1  
\end{array} \right]
$

$C)
\left[ \begin{array}{c|c}
A & B \\
\hline
C &  
\end{array} \right] = \left[ \begin{array}{cccc|c}
1&1&0&0&0 \\
0&1&1&0&0 \\
0&0&1&1&0 \\
0&0&0&1&1 \\
\hline
0&1&0&0  
\end{array} \right]
$

$D)
\left[ \begin{array}{c|c}
A & B \\
\hline
C &  
\end{array} \right] = \left[ \begin{array}{cccc|c}
1&1&0&0&0 \\
0&1&1&0&0 \\
0&0&1&1&0 \\
0&0&0&1&1 \\
\hline
0&1&0&0  
\end{array} \right]
$

$E)$ None of the above

I just found out how to calculate this but since I've gone through all the trouble of typing the question, I might ass well post it anyway. Maybe it helps someone else.

The answer can be found using $CA^{t-1}B$

So we get $CA^3B=1$ and $CA^{\neq 3}B=0$

We first try option $A$ which meets the criteria and thus is the only correct result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out how to calculate this but since I've gone through all the trouble of typing the question, I might ass well post it anyway. Maybe it helps someone else.

The answer can be found using $CA^{t−1}B$

So we get $CA^3B=1$ and $CA^{≠3}B=0$

We first try option A which meets the criteria and thus is the only correct result.